# Rotating a Secret Using a Custom Lambda Function

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, devops, aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager

How to write a lambda for a rotating secret (CDK in Typescript)where password changes every hour .

```
const templatedSecret = new secretsmanager.Secret(this, 'TemplatedSecret', {
      generateSecretString: {
        secretStringTemplate: JSON.stringify({ username: 'user' }),
        generateStringKey: 'password',
      },
    });

    new iam.User(this, 'OtherUser', {
      userName: templatedSecret.secretValueFromJson('username').toString(),
      password: templatedSecret.secretValueFromJson('password'),
    });
```

till now i only have this code and for reference i have https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-secretsmanager-readme.html#rotating-a-secret
But i am confused how to proceed and complete my desired task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your link states you need to add a schedule to your secret:

```
const fn = new lambda.Function(...);
const secret = new secretsmanager.Secret(this, 'Secret');

secret.addRotationSchedule('RotationSchedule', {
  rotationLambda: fn,
  automaticallyAfter: Duration.days(15)
});
```

Modify duration as needed. You also need to create a lambda function (fn) that will handle rotation. It is probably a generic secret that you need, so you should base your sample on this [template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/reference_available-rotation-templates.html#sar-template-generic).

You need to fill in the `set_secret` and `test_secret` methods. The `set_secret` sets the secret in your service. If it is a DB, it calls an API that updates the password of the user. If you don't need it, leave an empty application. The `test_secret` tests that the new secret is operational. An empty implementation will also work.

You also need to add lambda invoke permission for secrets manager. Something like this:

```
fn.addPermission('allowInvocation',{
  principal: new ServicePrincipal('secretsmanager.amazonaws.com')
})
```

In AWS Console, go to Lambda Configuration, scroll down to Resource-based policy and add the following Permission:

[image]

Comment: Your secret was created but configuring rotation has failed.
Secrets Manager cannot invoke the specified Lambda function. Ensure that the function policy grants access to the principal secretsmanager.amazonaws.com.(this error is coming )

Comment: You need to allow invocation from secretsmanager

Comment: And Sir i am trying it on console now ,not on cdk so while creating lambda function i am copying all the code given in SecretsManagerRotationTemplate/lambda_function.py /, but giving above error ,So please guide me what changes do i need to make to complete this task ..

Comment: Grant the permissions with CDK as stated in the answer.

Comment: arn = event['SecretId']
 token = event['ClientRequestToken'] { The ClientRequestToken of the secret version}
step = event['Step']{one of createSecret, setSecret, testSecret, or finishSecret} .                                                                                   It's asking these parameters to test the lambda function ARN can be seen in secret details only ,where to find other parameters to test the lambda .

Comment: The event is sent by secretsmanager, when invoking the function. You can try manually rotating the secret from AWS console. This will trigger the function and you can test it.